# What is the best way to automate this stat comparison task?

Tags: google-sheets

I play a game where 2 people play against each other to win money, the idea is that both people choose a Premier League player and a stat is randomly chosen, the player with the best stat wins.  There are 23 stat categories and I want to work out a way to find out which player has the biggest advantage.

If I have a table with 200 players and their stats for each of the 23 stat categories what is the best way to develop something that automatically compares all the players and all the stats and then creates a table to show which is the best player?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with examples of desired output

Comment: Good idea, never thought about that, thanks.  Here is the link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pNPlEUtbnQSFORz7eT7mTPB-MpZ_FBh_kTnWLQdFONA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If there is a better way of doing it other than using a spreadsheet I'm thinking of using one of the sites where you can hire somebody to do the work.  So any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: @FootstockChat it's not clear what the data means or what you are trying to do with it?

Comment: I've added some more info to the Google sheet in a separate tab.  Please let me know if you need more.